# Internal hdd auto-mounted for another user

Tags: mount, hard-drive

I'm running ubuntu 13.04, the system is hosted in one hdd. I've recently added a secondary hdd.

Everything is auto-mounted with the Disks GUI tool of ubuntu. It works for my session as main user of the system, it is mounted in /media/mat.

If a second user switch on the computer and log into his session, it can't mount the second hdd... ask for password.

And my goal was to share this hdd between users (with appropriate rights).

How can this hdd be mounted on start up of the PC for any users to use without root password ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the hard drive to /etc/fstab

edit /etc/fstab as root and add a line for the hard drive. Something like:

> /dev/sdb1 /media/second               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1

should work. If the filesystem is ext4 (or any file system that supports it) then normal Linux permissions will be in effect.

If you never bothered to format the drive for Linux and are using a FAT or NTFS file system you will be much better off formatting it using `mkfs` and `fdisk`

[This site](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-disk-format/) has pretty specific instructions including adding the new partition to fstab.

Keep in mind the /etc/fstab line above is only a sample. You will need to setit up correctly with the right device, mount point, and file system (not to mention options).

Comment: Just add to create a directory named "second" as root in /media, with "sudo mkdir /media/second" and your solution works... it's obvious but it can help some other people. Thanks coteyr. PS : the hdd was format as ext4.